# Como controlar a transação entre dois banco de dados distintos no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, transações

Possuo dois bancos de dados e preciso garantir a persistência dos dados nos dois em um determinado processo.

Os componentes de conexão são os do pacote Interbase Express.

Fiz assim:

```delphi
database := DataModule.IBDatabase;
databaseDois := TIBDatabase.Create(nil);
try
  try
    transaction := database.DefaultTransaction;
    transaction.StartTransaction;
    databaseDois.DefaultTransaction := transaction;
    databaseDois.LoginPrompt := false;
    databaseDois.Params.Text := database.Params.Text
    databaseDois.DatabaseName := 'databaseDois.gdb';
    query := TIBQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      query.Database := databaseDois;
      query.Transaction := transaction;
      // execução dos processo no segundo banco de dados.
    finally
      query.Free;
    end;
    // execução dos processos no database original
    transaction.Commit;
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      transaction.Rollback;
      raise e;
    end;
  end;
finally
  databaseDois.Free;
end;
```

O que fiz foi criar um segundo componente de conexão e utilizar o mesmo componente de transação para ambos. Porém, ao tentar executar uma query com a segunda conexão um erro é gerado:

> invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)

**É possivel fazer esse tipo de controle, como e, onde estou errando?**

Vejam que a transação já foi iniciada, como demonstrado a seguir:

[image: Transação Iniciada]

Answer (score 1):

Faltava apenas efetuar a abertura do **databaseDois** para meu exemplo funcionar.

```dephi
...
transaction := database.DefaultTransaction;
transaction.StartTransaction;
databaseDois.DefaultTransaction := transaction;
databaseDois.LoginPrompt := false;
databaseDois.Params.Text := database.Params.Text
databaseDois.DatabaseName := 'databaseDois.gdb';
databaseDois.Open; // falta apenas isso para funcionar
query := TIBQuery.Create(nil);
try
...
```

Comment: você pode aceitar sua resposta (o V abaixo do número de votos dela) daí ela não aparecerá mais como sem resposta.